# How can I make a string jump to a new line after a certain number of characters in PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

[image]

I am trying to put a string that is retrieved from my database, so it's kind of hard to split the string.

```
            XRect rect = new XRect(page8margin, page8margin + 60 + (3 * page8margin), 300, 300);
            gfx8.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.LightGray, rect);

            tf.DrawString(interview.Job.Summary, smallerFont, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

But it seems like the string is just ignoring the border and just written in one single line. How can I split the string and make it jump to a new line after a certain number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `XTextFormatter` (which you are probably using, judging by the variable name `tf` - thanks for showing that much code) breaks lines at blank characters.

Source code for `XTextFormatter` is included, so you can adapt it to your needs.

The text showing on the screen shot has one very long word and the default implementation of `XTextFormatter` does not break words, no matter how long they are.

It is a special requirement to break long words, but you can adapt the `XTextFormatter` class for that purpose. Or use the `XTextFormatter` class as inspiration to write your own code.

Maybe you just have to test with a "Lorem ipsum ..." paragraph to solve the issue.